# NUMAH LITTERS OV KITTEHS ON TEH NETZ

Tags: strings, 99-bottles-of-beer, lolcode

> It's not fair that 1% of the users hold 75% of the lolcode questions. #OccupyMatsMug
>   [~ user2296177](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=30952986#30952986)

I agree. Without further ado, here's the LOLCODE version of 99 bottles of beer on the wall:

```
OBTW
    PRINT TEH LOLCODE VERSHUN OV N BOTTLEZ OV BER ON TEH WALL.
TLDR

HAI 1.3

  HOW IZ I COUNTDOWN YR NUMAH
    I HAS A NAUW ITZ A NUMBR
    I HAS A LEZZ ITZ A NUMBR
    IM IN YR LOOPZ NERFIN YR COWNTR TIL BOTH SAEM COWNTR AN DIFF OF 1 AN NUMAH
      NAUW R SUM OF NUMAH AN COWNTR
      LEZZ R DIFF OF NAUW AN 1
      VISIBLE SMOOSH NAUW AN " LITTERS OV KITTEHS ON TEH NETZ" MKAY
      VISIBLE SMOOSH NAUW AN " LITTERS OV KITTEHS" MKAY
      VISIBLE "WAN FALLS DOWN AN BREAKZ PAH"
      VISIBLE SMOOSH LEZZ AN " LITTERS OV KITTEHS ON TEH NETZ" MKAY
      VISIBLE ""
    IM OUTTA YR LOOPZ

    VISIBLE "1 LITTER OV KITTEHS ON TEH NETZ"
    VISIBLE "1 LITTER OV KITTEHS"
    VISIBLE "WAN FALLS DOWN AN BREAKZ PAH"
    VISIBLE "NO MOAR LITTERs OV KITTEHS ON TEH NETZ"
  IF U SAY SO

  I IZ COUNTDOWN YR 99 MKAY

KTHXBYE
```

*Disclaimer: No actual kittens were harmed while writing this program.*

The number of iterations is held in the variable `NUMAH`. I know `NUMBR` is a more fitting name, but that's already claimed as a type.

The above is compiled using the latest [lci](https://github.com/justinmeza/lci) using the [1.3 specification](http://web.archive.org/web/20120420194728/http://lolcode.com/proposals/1.3/bukkit2) (thanks to Pimgd for the link). Since the 1.3 specification doesn't contain every feature of the language, see the [1.2 specification as well](https://github.com/justinmeza/lolcode-spec/blob/master/v1.2/lolcode-spec-v1.2.md).

I don't think LOLCODE has templates or the likes, so getting all the output on screen is a bit tedious.

Output:

```
99 LITTERS OV KITTEHS ON TEH NETZ
99 LITTERS OV KITTEHS
WAN FALLS DOWN AN BREAKZ PAH
98 LITTERS OV KITTEHS ON TEH NETZ
```

etc.

```
1 LITTER OV KITTEHS ON TEH NETZ
1 LITTER OV KITTEHS
WAN FALLS DOWN AN BREAKZ PAH
NO MOAR LITTERs OV KITTEHS ON TEH NETZ
```

Is this idiomatic LOLCODE?

Comment: Before I clicked this when I saw it in the HNQ I was like "Aww, I'm sure some buzzkills are gonna change that title", but look, 31 votes and 25 on a great answer, holy cats!

Comment: I thought this was PPCG at first, I was confused what was being asking for the longest time. Happy to see LOLCODE here!

Comment: @CaptainMan This is most definitely not PPCG, but we do know how to write great code :-)

Comment: Lolcode spec 1.2 for reference as well as v1.3 doesn't explain everything https://github.com/justinmeza/lolcode-spec/blob/master/v1.2/lolcode-spec-v1.2.md

Comment: @cat Punny titles are something of a tradition on Code Review (where they can be used to still communicate useful information about the code in question)

Comment: @CaptainMan this is, what I think, the antithesis of PPCG.

Comment: _"No actual kittens were harmed while writing this program."_ No, but I think my brain suffered some harm trying to read that.

Comment: @Pimgd Ah, yes, I guess I used part of the 1.2 specification as well. Added the link to the question for completeness sake.

Comment: Isn't indenting somehow against the spirit of LOLCODE?

Comment: "No actual kittens were harmed while writing this program." So this definitely isn't PPCG, where there is [undefined behaviour killed my cat](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22877/undefined-behavior-killed-my-cat)

Comment: @trichoplax Code Review being superior to PPCG when it comes to animal welfare: confirmed.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

### Variable capitalization

IT IZ PRETTY GUD LOLCODE
HOWEVEZ ME THINKS THAT TEH LOLCODEZ R EZYR 2 READ IF TEH VARZ R lowercase
ZIS BECUZ ALL CAPS IS HARD TOO READ
<sub>(all spelling "mistakes" made by my cat, who assisted me in that part of this review)</sub>

More seriously, it is an issue that there are no good LOLCODE syntax highlighters. To be "stylish" and keep everything uppercase is a choice you can make, but personally I prefer to use lowercase or camelCase variable names whilst keeping the language constructs all caps. Similar to SQL, this allows you to see what parts of the code are variables, and what parts are language constructs.

Compare:

```
I HAS A NAUW ITZ A NUMBR
I HAS A LEZZ ITZ A NUMBR
IM IN YR LOOPZ NERFIN YR COWNTR TIL BOTH SAEM COWNTR AN DIFF OF 1 AN NUMAH
  NAUW R SUM OF NUMAH AN COWNTR
  LEZZ R DIFF OF NAUW AN 1
  VISIBLE SMOOSH NAUW AN " LITTERS OV KITTEHS ON TEH NETZ" MKAY
  VISIBLE SMOOSH NAUW AN " LITTERS OV KITTEHS" MKAY
  VISIBLE "WAN FALLS DOWN AN BREAKZ PAH"
  VISIBLE SMOOSH LEZZ AN " LITTERS OV KITTEHS ON TEH NETZ" MKAY
  VISIBLE ""
IM OUTTA YR LOOPZ
```

with...

```
I HAS A nauw ITZ A NUMBR
I HAS A lezz ITZ A NUMBR
IM IN YR LOOPZ NERFIN YR cowntr TIL BOTH SAEM cowntr AN DIFF OF 1 AN numah
  nauw R SUM OF numah AN cowntr 
  lezz R DIFF OF nauw AN 1
  VISIBLE SMOOSH nauw AN " LITTERS OV KITTEHS ON TEH NETZ" MKAY
  VISIBLE SMOOSH nauw AN " LITTERS OV KITTEHS" MKAY
  VISIBLE "WAN FALLS DOWN AN BREAKZ PAH"
  VISIBLE SMOOSH lezz AN " LITTERS OV KITTEHS ON TEH NETZ" MKAY
  VISIBLE ""
IM OUTTA YR LOOPZ
```

### Variable naming

Regarding `NUMAH`, have you considered using `NUMBAH`? Similar meaning, but uses a more common mispronunciation.

### Working around the spec

```
IM IN YR LOOPZ NERFIN YR COWNTR TIL BOTH SAEM COWNTR AN DIFF OF 1 AN NUMAH
  NAUW R SUM OF NUMAH AN COWNTR
```

This construct is non-obvious. You had to work around the spec to do something that you wanted to do, and I think it warrants explanation. Add a comment via `BTW`:

```
IM IN YR LOOPZ NERFIN YR COWNTR TIL BOTH SAEM COWNTR AN DIFF OF 1 AN NUMAH
  NAUW R SUM OF NUMAH AN COWNTR BTW workaround loop counters starting at 0
```

### Correctness in corner cases

Your function doesn't check if the value passed in is greater than 0. This means that it falsely forces a KITTEH to break their paw when it wasn't necessary.

Add a guard clause at the top of the function; you can do an early return via `GTFO`.

```
DIFFRINT numbah AN BIGGR OF numbah AN 0
O RLY? YA RLY
    GTFO
OIC
```

### Program definition

```
OBTW
    PRINT TEH LOLCODE VERSHUN OV N BOTTLEZ OV BER ON TEH WALL.
TLDR

HAI 1.3
```

Aside from the weird phrasing (does this code print the lolcode version of/and bottles of beer on the wall?), there's something else wrong here: Your comment is before the `HAI 1.3`. So any interpreter loading your file might not know what version you are using. Put your version number at the top.

### Possible alternative dialects

```
VISIBLE "NO MOAR LITTERs OV KITTEHS ON TEH NETZ"
```

Did you make a typo here, is this an alternative kitty dialect that uses lower case 's' for certain plurals? I'm not sure.

---

Lastly, I think this version of 99 LITTERS OV KITTEHS ON TEH NETZ is not authentic, as anyone knows that when KITTEHS fall, they'll be alright. This version is sad, as all the KITTEHS just break their paws. Proper LOLCODE uses cats, it doesn't *abuse* them.

Comment: Definitely a typo there. Next time I'll try to write a more PG-themed poem.

Comment: This is how I saw PL/SQL when I started to learn it. Random `CAPITAL WORDS` and then some variables, all tidy up and stuff.

Comment: U NAH NEED TEH MOAR SRS VERRSIN; LOLCODRZ GET IT ANYWAYZ! OMG SRS LOLCODE HEER! YAH "NUMAH" NAH A WORD HEER.

Comment: Does Lolcode have a not-equals function?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes DIFFRINT `<X>` AN `<Y>` ... and I see, yeah, you could totally make the ending condition for the loop simpler with that.

Comment: Sorry, got myself turned around. I'm trying to figure out why you did `if numbah != max (numbah, 0)` when you could have just done `if numbah == 0`, so I wanted to know if there wasn't a built-in equals or something, but I asked the wrong thing.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes `DIFF OF 1 AN numbah` is `1 - numbah`. `BOTH SAEM cowntr AN ...` makes this `cowntr == (1 - numbah)`. You can't make that shorter, save for storing the result of `1 - numbah` in a variable.

Comment: I think I was unclear. In the last block, why did you do `DIFFRINT...` instead of `BOTH SAEM numbah AN 0`?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes What if there were -1 "LITTERS OV KITTEHS ON TEH NETZ"?

Comment: Oh, true. That smells of YAGNI to me, though.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes either you do the validation, or you don't do the validation at all... I don't quite see why checking for `>= 0` rather than `!= 0` makes for YAGNI?...

Comment: In Lolcode, it's a lot more code than that, and it doesn't really serve a purpose.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes the difference is `DIFFRINT numbah AN BIGGR OF numbah AN 0` vs `BOTH SAEM numbah AN 0` and this seems like a small difference to me. On the scale of "less than 30 seconds of work". I add such due diligence in my work where I can.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the phrasing. The original docstring was `Print the lolcode version of N bottles of beer on the wall`. However, since this is lolcode, the N was translated ambiguously.

Comment: @Mast replacing N with X solves the ambiguity